# Angular 2 : Call root component's method from nested child component

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have few components in my application:

```
//.ts:

RootComponent
-ParentComponent
--ChildComponent
---LastLevelComponent


//.html

<root-component>
 <parent-component>
   <child-component>
     <last-level-component></last-level-component>
   </child-component>
 </parent-component>
</root-component>
```

I want to call a method of Rootcomponent from LastLevelComponent.

> Am aware of EventEmitter, but problem with that is I need to pass
>   value to each child component.
>   Is there any way I can call directly
>   RootComponent's method from LastLevelComponent without having
>   dependency on ParentComponent or ChildComponent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `@Input()` in your `LastLevelComponent`.
Or an `@Output()` without Child- and ParentComponent needs to use this Event.

```
//.html

<root-component #rootCmp>
 <parent-component>
   <child-component>
     <last-level-component [root-comp]="rootCmp" (myOutput)"rootCmp.func()"></last-level-component>
   </child-component>
 </parent-component>
</root-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating a service. Follow these steps:

1. Create a service

@Injectable()
export class CompService {

```
private componentRef = null;

constructor(){
}

getParent(){
    return this.componentRef;
}

setParent(ref){
    this.componentRef = ref;
}
```

}

2. Include this service in your root component, in providers section:

@Component({
    . . .

```
providers: [CompService]
```

})
export class RootComponent {

```
constructor(
    private cmpService?: CompService)
{
}
```

}

3. During initialization of the root component, call the service to set the component value to point to the root:

   ngOnInit(){
       this.cmpService.setParent(this);
   }
4. In child component or last level component, call this service to retrieve the root component:

@Component({
    . . .
})
export class LastLevelComponent {

```
constructor(
    private cmpService?: CompService)
{
}   

someMethod(){
   if (this.cmpService){
      let parentCtrl = this.cmpService.getParent();

      // Call your parent method or property here
      // if (parentCtrl)
      // parentCtrl.rootMethod();
   }
}
```

}

You may notice that CompService is **only** set in providers section of root component. This enables to have one instance of this service. So all child components will inherit the service settings pointing to the root component.

You only need to call the getParent method of the service in each child component to get access to the root component public methods, properties and events.

Furthermore, this service is reusable and avoids dependency of any other component.